# Measure ≥ 200ns pulses (width and interval) as precisely as possible

Tags: measurement, high-frequency, high-speed

I have a 0..5 V digital signal with a minimum pulse width of 200 ns.

I would like to measure the pulse width and the time between the rising edges of pulses.

In my case it would be enough to measure the incoming signal for 500..1000 ms to get the pulse, send the measurements to a microcontroller and then start over.

What would be the best method to measure it as precisely as possible with the minimum of components?

Comment: what exactly does "the pulses between 500 ms and 1 s" mean? Do you mean these that happen between these times, or do you mean pulses with widths between half a second and full a second?

Comment: i meant that i dont need to measure the incoming signal constantly. it' senough to measure the signal for 500ms to 1s  to get the pulse width and etc. and then send data to a MCU and that measure again for 500ms to 1s.

Comment: Why do you need to measure separately and send to MCU? A properly selected MCU could measure the signal with 0 external components.

Comment: I already have a MCU (ATmega4809) in my circuit that is controlling the rest of my circuit. I have tried it with interrupts on the 4809 while running the rest and the performance was pretty bad. So i thought to use another MCU or an IC that is capable of measuring such signal and then send the data to the main MCU.

Comment: The "best" method and using the "minimum" components are not compatible. Is your signal continuous? What does this mean --> *and then start over*?

Comment: What resolution do you need? Is it enough to know that it's <200, 400, 600, 800, etc. ns, or do you need to know 201.47ns level of detail? How many pulses arrive in the 500-1000ms window, and which one(s) do you need to measure, or do statistics on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really sounds like a job for the Timer/Counter Unit of your microcontroller. Your ATMega4809 definitely has multiple of these (at least TCA, TCB, but probably a lot more).

You can program them to count the clock cycles (== time) between a rising and a falling input edge – no interrupts for accurate timing needed. The Timer/Counter Unit then writes the count to a specific location, and you have all the time in the world (until the next pulse) to save that value somewhere before it gets overridden.

Comment: After tinkering a little bit. It is indeed possible to use the timers to messure such high speed with the 4809. Now i need to implement it to the rest of my code. Thank you.

Comment: @ArtjomEske glad to hear you got it to work! Note that basically all microcontrollers have such timer units – some are more, some are less versatile than these of the ATMega, but in general, pulse duration measurement is a common feature. There's more modern microcontrollers than the ATMega4809 (which also might be much cheaper; for example, for its price, you get a whole [solderable microcontroller](https://mou.sr/3Xwi4mr) board with Bluetooth and Wifi built in, and a counter rate of 40 MHz, so you can measure pulse lengths with a precision of down to 25 ns (assuming analog bandwidth agrees))

Answer (score -1):

Usually, some 8 bit and 16 bit CPUs such as NXP S08, Infineon and others can measure pulse edges spaced 20 μS or more. Measuring pulse edges in 200 ns or 0.2 μS scale is really not possible even with medium speed MCUs with a clock speed around 40 MHz.The GPIO signal detection accuracy of a MCU is perhaps in 5 μS range. If you want to do edge detection of pulses at 200 nano ns scale, a FPGA or a custom ASIC might be used for the best solution. In milli or micro second scale, it can be done with keyboard interrupts or any edge or level interrupt of GPIO pins or input capture module which uses a timer.

Comment: hm, I've seen multiple implementations that build PWM-style signalling receivers (like in the WS2812 "neopixels") with normal microcontrollers and their counter units. I don't see how this is "impossible". No, nothing in a 40 MHz CPU limits any input to periods of more than a few µs. I mean, if that was the case, the fastest external signal you could observe with a MCU's GPIO would be slower than 2 kHz – that's definitely wrong.

Comment: 200 ns is 0.2 μS which is nearly impossible. I had actually generated PWM pulses in a few μS width but I think doing input capture with a pulse width of 0.2 μS is difficult. One may get errors if there is some jitter in interrupts. I believe I'm not wrong in this. I only said what you can do without defects in design and implementation from a system engineering point of view.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect what is practically possible.

Comment: As said, it's pretty trivially possible. That's literally what these counter units are for. The clock frequency of said counter is 20 MHz, 20 MHz / 2, 20 MHz / 4… or 20 MHz / 64 (on the ATMega4809 that OP is using). So, you can very well measure pulse durations down to 1/(20 MHz) = 50 ns with this.

Comment: Of course iit is possible in hardware in 50 or 100 ns as you said.When you add software functionality, it becomes slow.  The interrupt firing sequence has some delay and executing a function in C/C++ takes about 1 μS. Starting the ISR takes upto 0.5 to 1 μS.. I assume that the counting of pulse widths happens in a ISR or a function call.  If you add all these delays, you can actually measure pule widthss of a few μS.

Comment: Amit, sorry, this is plain wrong. There's zero interrupt that software has to handle here. The counting happens in the timer/counter hardware, as said.

Comment: @AmitM That's why you need timer with DMA functionality for input capture. So it is very well possible on MCUs.

Comment: Marcus Müller , the TPM (timer) clock may not be accurate in say 50 ns scale because the oscillator/crystal on most 8 bit MCU is not accurate.

Comment: As @MarcusMüller stated in his answer to my question. It is possible and i got my timings. When i trying to measure my 200ns, my counter is up to 3..4 which means that i'm indeed sample every 50ns.

Comment: @AmitM no other method would get any better. The shorter the meausured interval, the less problematic the error due to clock error. Software-sampling would only make this worse, as the CPU clock is derived from the same clock, so that's yet another reason why trying to do it in software is not really sensible here.

Comment: Marcus Müller, Are you trying to imply that you detect pulse width with hardware and then read that value with software? If so, are you trying to read a past reading which was done somewhere 200 or 500 ns before the software reads it because software can work slowly compared to hardware and you are reading always the past values. This doesn't really match some hardware requirements. I had worked on several engineering designs in which the reading of some value or a sensor should be in recent 50ms or 50 μS whatever that interval may be.

Comment: Marcus Müller, This is where I meant hardware requirements dont match for values read which may be incoherent with current state of a application. I meant reading pulse width for any pulse as it occurs without "missing" any pulses. Please clarify.